# Unable to access home server via VPN (double VPN setup)

Tags: vpn, iptables

I have a local server running at home that is connected to a external VPN so that all traffic, except local, is routed via it. I also have a private VPN setup at home. My problem is that I am unable to access my home server remotely via my private home-VPN. I am able to access my server when it is not connected to the external VPN, so I know (or at least think) I have my home-VPN correctly setup. If anyone know what causes my problem, help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your VPN uses a different subnet than your home network. Your server is configured to route *all* traffic, except the home network, over the VPN. That means it will send the return traffic to your computer connected via private VPN also over the external VPN.

You need to add a route for the private VPN to the server's routing table (assuming it's Linux):

```
ip route add 192.168.100.0/24 via 192.168.0.1
```

Where `192.168.100.0/24` is your private VPN subnet and `192.168.0.1` is the VPN terminator for the private VPN.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the help. Will try to fix it later.